# How to create a html form that parses a local file along with storing inputted values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I attempting to make a form that a user can upload a file to it and at the time of submitting it, it can A: parse the uploaded file AND B: store the other values submitted.

My HTML (Jade) looks like this

```
    form#form
            input(type="number" name="bufferNum" placeholder="Number") 
            label 
                input(type="radio" name="bufferType" value="Miles") 
                span Miles
            label 
                input(type="radio" name="bufferType" value="Feet") 
                span Feet
            label 
                input(type="radio" name="bufferType" value="Kilometers") 
                span Kilometers
            label 
                input(type="radio" name="bufferType" value="Meters") 
                span Meters
            label 
               input(type="radio" name="bufferType" value="Degrees") 
               span Degrees
            input(type="file" id="file" name="bufferFile")
            input(type="button" value="Buff")
```

My JS looks like this

```
    //FILE LOADER
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files, // FileList object
            f = files[0],
            reader = new FileReader();
        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) { 
                var JsonObj = e.target.result,
                    parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JsonObj),
                    featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(parsedJSON).addTo(map);
            };
        })(f);
        // Read in JSON as a data URL.
        reader.readAsText(f, 'UTF-8');
    }


    $( "#form input[type='button']" ).on('click', function(e) {
        var bufferNum =  $( 'input[name="bufferNum"]' ).val();
        var bufferType = $( 'input[name="bufferType"]' ).val();
        var bufferFile = $( 'input[name="bufferFile"]' ).val();
        handleFileSelect(bufferFile); //THIS DOES NOT WORK
        return false;
    });
```

A codepen of the issue is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNpYjB?editors=101

Thank you in advance. Trying to wrap my head around the HTML File API has been tricky

Answer (score 0):

You should call `handleFileSelect` like this

```
var bufferFile = $( 'input[name="bufferFile"]' );
handleFileSelect(bufferFile[0]);
```

Modify handleFileSelect like this

```
function handleFileSelect(file) {
    var files = file.files, // FileList object
        f = files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) { 
        console.log(reader.result); // here is the data from the file.
    };
    reader.readAsText(f, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Here is the updated demo **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqPPyL?editors=001**

Hope this helps.